# Should the [restrict] and [restrict-qualifier] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

These two tags seem to be talking about the same thing (restricted pointers in C and C++).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier

Comment: It seems wrong for two things marked 'restrict' to point at the same destination...

Comment: NO, they aren't pointing to the same thing! https://stackoverflow.com/q/52181930/792066

Comment: @Briam:  This particular use of the [restrict] tag doesnt seem appropriate

Comment: They should be synonyms, of course, but because so many people have misused the [[tag:restrict]] tag, they have to be manually disambiguated. That makes this a much larger, time-consuming, and disruptive process. [[meta-tag:status-deferred]] for now.